# How can I order records from newest to oldest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This my code:

```
@statuses = []
current_user.friends.each do |f|
  @statuses = @statuses + f.statuses 
end
@sorted_statuses = @statuses.sort_by { |obj| obj.created_at }
```

I'm taking all my friends statuses from the database and puting them on the wall.
I'm trying to show them from the new (at the top) to the old (at the bottom), buy right now its vice versa. Please let me know how to change it.

Answer (score 8):

No need to pre-declare the array, or post process on another line.  the ordering can be done via database.  The ruby way is:

```
@statuses = current_user.friends.order('created_at DESC').collect {|f| f.statuses}
```

Comment: its not working, im not getting at error but its still from the old to the new.

Comment: Allowing the database to do the sorting also means that, should the number of results be larger than you really want back, you can limit the number of results you get back from the database and still make sure you have the newest ones, in order.

Answer (score 0):

You can even define the default order in your model with [`default_scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-default_scope)

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope order('last_name, first_name')
end
```